# How to delete all fields created in MarkLogic

Tags: field, marklogic

I have a requirement whereby existing fields needs to be deleted. I found perfect script for deletion of field-range indexes but not for fields.
So, I wrote this script which works fine but I need to pass each field-name one by one :

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

  import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin"
          at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

  let $config := admin:get-configuration()
  let $dbid := xdmp:database("testDB")
  let $fields := admin:database-get-fields($config,$dbid)
  for $each in $fields
  let $config := admin:database-delete-field($config, $dbid,$each/*:field-name/fn:string())
  return admin:save-configuration($config)
```

Does anyone else has a better solution for this? Whereby we can directly pass fields and it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [admin:database-delete-field()](https://docs.marklogic.com/admin:database-delete-field) accepts multiple field names, so you can skip the FLWOR:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin"
      at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

let $config := admin:get-configuration()
let $dbid := xdmp:database("testDB")
let $fields := admin:database-get-fields($config,$dbid)
let $config := admin:database-delete-field($config, $dbid, $fields/*:field-name)
return admin:save-configuration($config)
```

That said, if you find yourself in a position where you cannot avoid a FLWOR, use xdmp:set to iteratively update $config, and finish with a single save-config. Your code was executing that for each FLWOR iteration. Something like this should work too:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin"
      at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

let $config := admin:get-configuration()
let $dbid := xdmp:database("testDB")
let $fields := admin:database-get-fields($config,$dbid)
let $_ :=
    for $each in $fields
    return xdmp:set($config, admin:database-delete-field($config, $dbid, $each/*:field-name))
return admin:save-configuration($config)
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for you input, it really helped.